# PAM updates for mounting an encrypted user's home at login (GNOME 40.4.0)

Tags: linux, centos, gnome, redhat-enterprise-linux, pam

I would like to decrypt my LUKS encrypted `/home` directory at login on Rocky Linux 9.1. I have been trying to adapt this Arch Linux guide (https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Mounting_at_login; https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Talk:Dm-crypt/Mounting_at_login) and this GitHub repo (https://github.com/fumiyas/linux-crypthome) for Rocky 9.1. `/etc/pam.d/system-login` does not exist for Rocky, so I have updated `/etc/postlogin` and `/etc/system-auth` with `pam_exec.so` calls to a custom script (`/usr/local/sbin/pam_cryptsetup.sh`) that will decrypt and mount my encrypted `/home` directory. The updates I made to `/etc/pam.d/postlogin` and `system-auth` allow me to `ssh` into my machine but login from the GNOME login screen fails. If I am already logged in from `ssh` and then login from the GNOME login screen, that will work. Does anyone know how to update the scripts in `/etc/pam.d/` to enable GNOME screen login or have any bright ideas?

```
# cat /usr/local/sbin/pam_cryptsetup.sh
#!/bin/sh

CRYPT_USER="user"
PARTITION="/dev/vg_alnair/crypthome.$CRYPT_USER"
NAME="decrypthome.$CRYPT_USER"
# PW=$(cat /dev/stdin)
# echo $PW > /tmp/pw.$PAM_USER

if [ "$PAM_USER" = "$CRYPT_USER" ] && [ ! -e "/dev/mapper/$NAME" ]; then
    logger "$(basename $0): $PAM_USER: decrypting /dev/mapper/$NAME"
    /usr/sbin/cryptsetup open "$PARTITION" "$NAME"
    status=$?
    if [ $status -eq 0 ]; then
    logger "$(basename $0): cryptsetup success for $PAM_USER!: $status"
    else
    logger "$(basename $0): cryptsetup failed for $PAM_USER!: $status"
    fi
else
    logger "$(basename $0): $PAM_USER: not decrypting anything!"
fi
```

Here are some outputs from journalctl after failing to login from the GNOME login screen:

```
# journalctl -r -t gdm-password]
Mar 20 17:46:59 alnair gdm-password][1851]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session closed for user user
Mar 20 17:46:56 alnair gdm-password][1851]: pam_exec(gdm-password:session): /usr/local/sbin/pam_cryptsetup.sh failed: exit code 13
Mar 20 17:46:56 alnair gdm-password][1894]: pam_exec(gdm-password:session): execve(/usr/local/sbin/pam_cryptsetup.sh,...) failed: Permission denied
Mar 20 17:46:56 alnair gdm-password][1851]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly
Mar 20 17:46:56 alnair gdm-password][1851]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Mar 20 17:46:56 alnair gdm-password][1851]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user user(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Mar 20 17:46:56 alnair gdm-password][1851]: pam_systemd(gdm-password:session): Failed to create session: Job 2126 for unit 'session-4.scope' failed with 'dependency'
Mar 20 17:45:26 alnair gdm-password][1860]: pam_exec(gdm-password:auth): Calling /usr/local/sbin/pam_cryptsetup.sh ...
Mar 20 17:45:26 alnair gdm-password][1851]: pam_exec(gdm-password:auth): send password to child
```

Comment: Just like that page says, this seems very much like you're reinventing existing tools like pam_mount (or systemd-homed) in a much more brittle way. Have you evaluated the existing solutions first?

Comment: @user1686, so far as I can tell, pam_mount is not included in `/lib64/security` with all the other `pam` modules on Rocky Linux 9 and I can't find it via `dnf` (with EPEL enabled). There also isn't much on using `systemd-homed` on RHEL 9 derivatives. I would also like to get to the bottom of why this works for `ssh` login, but not for a GNOME session login.